# concurrent processing of datareader results

Tags: c#, multithreading, datareader

My goal is to achieve better performance reading the results returned from a Datareader. Consider below example to understand the problem better.

We have say 10 result set returned from a datareader. When we loop through these records to populate our object, the total time taken is around 3sec., now I have been asked to some how get this done below 1sec.

Can this be achieved by processing the read operation concurrently with in the datareader? If yes how can we do this?

```
IDataAccessMapper _dataAccessMapper;

var query = new StringBuilder();
query.Append("SELECT * FROM Step01");
query.Append("SELECT * FROM Step02");
query.Append("SELECT * FROM Step03");
......
query.Append("SELECT * FROM Step10");
var selCommand = dbContracts.GetTextCommand(query.ToString());
var dataReader = selCommand.AsReader();
while (dataReader.Read()){
    //Do something
}

var step1Details = new Collection<Step1Details>
if (dataReader.NextResult()){
    _dataAccessMapper.MapRecords<Step1Details>(dataReader, step1Details);
}
var step2Details = new Collection<Step2Details>
if (dataReader.NextResult()){
    _dataAccessMapper.MapRecords<Step2Details>(dataReader, step2Details);
}
....
....
var step10Details = new Collection<Step10Details>
if (dataReader.NextResult()){
    _dataAccessMapper.MapRecords<Step10Details>(dataReader, step10Details);
}
....
```

Comment: Why don't you just make different threads to handle each query in parallel?

Comment: I don't think it will help that much. To reduce processing time, you should look for code optimisation and database query optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

The DataReader is not guaranteed to be thread safe, although I think the issue derives from the Connection class which is not thread safe. What you can do is to run seperate threads (with their own Connection) to perform the individual select statements and process the data concurrently. This will also ensure that each thread uses its own DataReader.

Note, there is an option to perform multi-threading using the same Connection in SQL Server, called MARS (multi active record sets). But I don't think that will be a good approach for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks you Neill, We tried to run individual queries and finally used Task library to process the data. But still the results was not good :(

Comment: Then you will have to look at your queries itself, for example do not make use of dynamic queries, rather use views or stored procedures to ensure that the query plans are pre-determined and optimize. Make sure that you only fetch columns that you need. Ensure that you have the appropriate indexes in-place, especially if you perform 'where' and 'joins'. The other option is to perform local caching on startup of your application.